# Determine the probability that 1 of the 4 tickets bought is the winning ticket

Tags: probability

> One hundred tickets are sold for a raffle at a dance, and three are drawn randomly to win a prize. Determine the probability that 1 in 4 of these tickets that Jason bought is one of these winning tickets

I'm having trouble with this question, can someone please just push me in the direction to help me find the answer?

Comment: Do you mean at least one or exactly one?

Comment: Count (1) all the possible sequences of 4 tickets, and (2) all the possible sequences of 4 tickets with 1 winning ticket

Comment: @lulu I believe the question implies exactly 1.

Comment: @lulu: Which posted solution are you referring to ?

Comment: @trueblueanil  Your solution is exact, the other is a decent approximation.  If I haven't screwed it up (always possible) your method gives about $.1128$ while the approximation gives $.1095$, so the difference is meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom31\binom{97}3$ ways Jason could have exactly $1$ winning and $3$ non-winning tickets.

Against this, Jason could have got any $4$ tickets in  $\binom{100}{4}$ combos.

Thus $Pr = \dfrac{\binom31\binom{97}{3}}{\binom{100}4}$

Comment: Would it not be 4 instead of 3 because theres a total of 4 tickets that Jason has?

Comment: $1$ winning ticket from $3$ winning ones, + $3$ non-winning tickets from $97$ non-winning ones. So Jason *does* have $1+3 = 4$ tickets !

Comment: are both solutions posted correct? I notice barak has 4 and 1, while you have 3, 1

Comment: Have you studied the hypergeometric distribution, drawing w/o replacement ? It is the appropriate formula for a raffle and gives the *exact* answer. Barak Manos has used the binomial distribution which here will give an *approximate* answer. So the formulas will naturally differ.

Comment: I'm in a grade 12 Data Management course, we have learned drawing w/ and w/o replacement but for decks of cards(Explicitly stating whether or not the cards are replaced or not) if that's what you mean?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly state it here. In a 100 ticket raffle, tickets would typically be numbered from $001-100$, and the same number can't go to more than one person, so it is without replacement.